# Access database reference in firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am struggling to access document references in the firestore rules. My database looks like this. (Simplified for brevity):

```
curriculum 
   session1

roles
   admin
       --- canEditContent
   user
       --- canEditContent

users
   userid
      --- role
          roles/admin <document reference>
```

I want to access the admin permissions based on the document reference.

I have tried several ways however can't seem to get anywhere. This is my code so far

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    function getUser() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
    function getUserRole() {
      let role = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role;
      return get(role);
    }
    match /curriculum/{curriculum} {
      allow write: if isSignedIn() && getUserRole().data.canEditContent;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried many ways and can't seem to solve it.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Added screenshots below of collections

Users collection showing role as a document ref to a role document in the roles collection.
[image: Users collection]

Roles collection
[image: Roles collection]

Comment: Without seeing all the actual data in the database, as well the client code that makes the query that should be rejected or allowed, what you have here is just theoretical.  Rules don't have any meaning without data and client code to work with.  Also consider that the local emulator is a much more effective way debug your client code and test data. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

Comment: I have added screenshots @DougStevenson and I will take a look at the local emulator. Thanks!

Comment: Please also show the code for the client query that you expect to be allowed or rejected by these rules.  We need to be able to see how all this data is tied together at the time of the query.  Specific values matter a lot here, both data and query.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two issues in your rules:

1. `get` needs the full document path, so your function `getUserRole` wont work. Try this instead:

   ```
   function getUserRole() {
     let role = getUser().data.role;
     return get(path("/databases/" + database + "/documents/" + role));
   }
   ```
2. Your rule uses the role `canEditContent` but the data you show uses `editContent`, is that on purpose?

As already mentioned please provide the complete set of data & query & rules, here we cant see the query you are using. Also note that you can use the Firestore emulator to get information on what rule is failing and where.

Comment: But a document reference includes the full path as far as I know?